# How can one become a resident of the United Nations?

Tags: residency, united-nations

I read on the registration form for [KLM airline](https://www.klm.com):

[image]

How can one establish residency in the United Nations? I.e., how can one become a resident of the United Nations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can't.  The web page is implemented carelessly.

They probably use the same source for that list as they do for "nationality," which is actually a list of travel-document-issuing authorities and therefore includes the UN, which issues a laissez-passer to its officers and employees.